# Создание своего адаптера для ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

Помогите, люди, ну совсем не понимаю эту тему.
Я беру данные из локальной БД и с помощью курсора раскидываю их в два ArrayList. (intValue - значение для фильтра)

```
final Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query("products", new String[] {DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_NAME, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_COUNT, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_LIST, DatabaseProductHelper.PRODUCT_TYPE},  null, null,  null, null, null) ;  
final ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
final ArrayList<String> arrTblCounts = new ArrayList<String>();

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("list"))==intValue) {
            arrTblNames.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));
            arrTblCounts.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("count")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")));
        }
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Все. Данные в двух ArrayList-ах. Моя задача - выводить данные из первого - в левый TextView, а из второго - в средний. 
Я подготовил соответствующую разметку и у меня получилось это!

```
san = arrTblNames.toArray(new String[0]);
myArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map;

for(int a = 0; a<san.length; a++) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", arrTblNames.get(a));
    map.put("count", arrTblCounts.get(a));
    myArrList.add(map);
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myArrList, R.layout.row, new String[] { "name", "count" }, new int[] { R.id.name_product, R.id.count_product});
lv_products.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Все отлично выводится, но...
**КАК ДОБАВИТЬ CheckBox?**
Флажок также должен работать с БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам нужно не создавать два отдельных ArrayList для каждого элемента разметки, а нужно создать объект, который вы будете инициализировать данными из БД, и передавать `ArrayList<CustomObject>` в ваш адаптер.
Объект будет выглядеть к примеру так

```
public class CustomObject {
    public String name;
    public int count;
    public boolean isChecked;
}
```

А наполнять созданный массив объектов можно так

```
  final ArrayList<CustomObject> items = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("list")) == intValue) {
                        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject();
                        customObject.count = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("count")) + " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
                        customObject.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                        items.add(customObject);
                    }
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

Соответственно вы теперь можете добавлять в ваш CustomObject любые поля и отображать их в вашем листвью